# Passing binding through Navigation Link crashes the app

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

Here is the navigation stack

All recipes > specific recipe > ingredients > specific ingredient

**All recipes View**

```
struct RecipesScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionData: SessionData
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List() {
                ForEach($sessionData.familyData.familyRecipes, id: \.self) { $recipe in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditRecipeScreen(recipe: $recipe)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(recipe.originalRecipe.title)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Specific recipe View**

```
struct EditRecipeScreen: View {
    @Binding var recipe: FamilyRecipe
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionData: SessionData
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // title
            TextField("Title", text: $recipe.originalRecipe.title)
            
            // ingredients >
            NavigationLink {
                IngredientsList(ingredients: $recipe.originalRecipe.ingredients)
            } label: {
                Text("Ingredients")
            }

            // cook >
            NavigationLink {
                InstructionsNavigation(instructions: $recipe.originalRecipe.cookInstructions, minutes: $recipe.originalRecipe.minutesToCook, type: "cook")
            } label: {
                Text("Cooking steps")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Ingredients View**

```
struct IngredientsList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionData: SessionData
    @Binding var ingredients: [RecipeIngredient]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach($ingredients, id: \.ingredient.id) { $recipeIngredient in
                NavigationLink {
                    IngredientView(recipeIngredient: $recipeIngredient)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(recipeIngredient.ingredient.displayName)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(recipeIngredient.amount.removeZerosFromEnd()) \(recipeIngredient.measure.description)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Specific ingredient View**

```
struct IngredientView: View {
    @Binding var recipeIngredient: RecipeIngredient
    
    var body: some View {

            Text("\(recipeIngredient.ingredient.displayName)")
            Text(recipeIngredient.ingredient.measure.description)

    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code but everything works up to the point where I tap on the navigation link to take me to the **Specific ingredient view** and my phone crashes.

If I place the 2 text fields from the Specific Ingredient View directly in the navigation link then it does not crash.

Another, possibly important, piece of information is that when it crashes the crash doesn't show in Xcode, my phone just freezes and I can no longer interact with the app but it remains open on the phone and Xcode shows nothing in the logs.

If I change the recipeIngredient variable in the Specific Ingredient View to a @State and pass it in without binding, it also works. But I pass through a binding through a navigation link from the all recipes view, so can't figure out why it's not working. I need the binding as I need to update the original ingredient in each case.

Any help would be so appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `\.ingredient.id` seems odd are all the `recipeIngredient` unique? What does the crash say? The identifier for a `ForEach` must be unique and stable.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs at all when the crash happens, the app just becomes unresponsive on my phone. With the `\.ingredient.id`, you're right that can be changed to `\.self` but I tried it and it still crashes.

Comment: I've also tried removing the `ForEach` completely and using `List($ingredients...` but the same happens

Comment: What does the crash say? `self` is as dangerous as `\.ingredient.id`

Comment: Console doesn't reflect the crash, it shows nothing, just as if the app was still working.

Comment: You are probably dealing with an infinite loop

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour with two views with bindings and stuck on it.  So Initial view with the ForEach passes a binding.  Then this view has another ForEach with another binding and it gets caught in an infinite loop when I tap it with no errors in console.  

If I change the top most view from NavigationStack to NavigationView it works correctly.  Does anyone know why NavigationStack would cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

`id: \.self` is a mistake you must supply a real `id` to the `ForEach` or it'll crash as you experience. A simple way to fix this is make your model struct conform to `Identifiable` then you don't need to supply an `id` param.